# What is AdobeFnt13.lst?

Tags: adobe-indesign

New to Indesign, I cannot open this font file. AdobeFnt13.lst

Are these standard adobe fonts.

I found this file on github https://github.com/witness/Obtaining-Informed-Consent/blob/master/Media/Document%20fonts/AdobeFnt13.lst and it is simply a listing of fonts.

Answer (score 5):

These are font cache files used by Adobe applications. They are **not** fonts. These files are not meant to be opened and explored. In fact, they can **freely** be deleted whenever needed and the applications will regenerate them as necessary.

In many cases, if font's fail to appear in applications trashing all AdobeFnt*.lst files may help.