# Font appears in Illustrator but not in InDesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, fonts

I am using a font (the lovely [Sprat](http://www.ethannakache.com/sprat) by Ethan Nakache) for a project and cannot get it to work in InDesign – it doesn't show up in the Type menu. It appears and works fine in Illustrator as well as Photoshop, so I am a bit confused about it not working in ID.

Things I have tried (so far without success):

- add font to Applications/Indesign/Fonts folder
- add font to "Document fonts" folder next to .indd file
- restart InDesign, Mac, Fontbase
- re-download font from different source
- check if the font appears in the menu under a different name
- deleted all Adobefntlist files

Any ideas on what causes this issue? How does InDesign handle fonts differently from Illustrator?

Answer (score 0):

Tech support if off topic..

**However**.. You might try clearing the boot drive of `adobefnt*.lst` files. If you search the boot volume for "AdobeFnt" you'll likely find hundreds of these `.lst` files. Quit InDesign, trash them all, then relaunch InDesign.

Related: [What is AdobeFnt13.lst?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/what-is-adobefnt13-lst)

Comment: Thank you @Scott for the suggestion, sadly it didn't help. I knew the question would be considered off-topic – I was hoping that it was caused by some odd InDesign-Quirk, that someone here has dealt with before.

Answer (score 0):

**Check Your “Block Untrusted Fonts” Setting**

In Windows 10, there is an option to block untrusted fonts. When this is on, it blocks Adobe fonts from activating. If you are working on a personal machine with Windows 10 Home, this is probably not the issue.

Steps to achieve this

> 1. Open the Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc) and go to Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Mitigation Options\Untrusted Font Blocking.

> 2. Click Enabled to turn the feature on, and then click one of the following Mitigation Options:

- Block untrusted fonts and log events. Turns the feature on, blocking
  untrusted fonts and logging installation attempts to the event log.
- Do not block untrusted fonts. Turns the feature on, but doesn't block
  untrusted fonts nor does it log installation attempts to the event
  log.
- Log events without blocking untrusted fonts. Turns the feature on,
  logging installation attempts to the event log, but not blocking
  untrusted fonts.

> 3 Click **OK**.

You can see the rest steps here how to ***Turn on and off the Blocking Untrusted Fonts feature***
using this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20Group%20Policy%20editor,untrusted%20fonts%20and%20log%20events.).

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include the essential parts of the linked resource. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.